# Jbeahve - convert enum parameters

Tags: enums, jbehave

I'm using jbehave in my project.

the story:

```
Scenario: Basic new document creation
Given a user Micky Mouse
When new document created
Then document should named new document
And document status should be NEW
```

my code:

```
/snip
    @Then("document status should be $status")
        public void documentStatusShouldBe(@Named("status") DocStatus status) {
            System.out.println(activeDocument.getStatus());
            assertThat(activeDocument.getStatus(), equalTo(status));
        }
/snip
```

my enum:

```
public enum DocStatus {
    NEW, IN_PROGRESS, APPROVE
}
```

when i ren my test i get:

> org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder$RunningStoriesFailed: Failures in
>   running stories:
>   ReportsCount[stories=1,storiesNotAllowed=0,storiesPending=0,scenarios=1,scenariosFailed=1,scenariosNotAllowed=0,scenariosPending=0,stepsFailed=1]
>     at
>   org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder$ThrowingRunningStoriesFailed.handleFailures(Embedder.java:499)
>     at
>   org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.handleFailures(Embedder.java:265)
>     at
>   org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.generateReportsView(Embedder.java:252)
>     at
>   org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.generateReportsView(Embedder.java:233)
>     at
>   org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.runStoriesAsPaths(Embedder.java:212)
>     at org.jbehave.core.junit.JUnitStory.run(JUnitStory.java:24)    at
>   stories.DocStories.run(DocStories.java:34)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

What i'm doing worng?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your embedder (typically the story class) needs to explicitly add the EnumConverter to the list of known ones:

```
configuration().useParameterConverters(
    configuration().parameterConverters().addConverters(
          new ParameterConverters.EnumConverter() ) );
```

JBehave does not add this converter per default (See ParmeterConverters.defaultConverters())

Comment: We are using jbehave 3.9, and the EnumConverter is there by default.

Comment: didn't help me, the only thing which is work for me is total deletion of the jbehave report folder...